# How to apply backspace \x08 to a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a utf-8 list variable lines like this:
`[u'  ASUS-ASUS-131:66   BF-24-XX-XX-BF--More-- \x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08         \x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08-A0,'u'                                               ASUS-ASUS-084:R0   AX-24-AX-AC-AX-10]`

If I do `print lines` it will print same as above with backspace \x08
but if I print line by line
`for i in lines`
    `print i`

It will print
`ASUS-ASUS-131:66   BF-24-XX-XX-BF-A0
ASUS-ASUS-084:R0   AX-24-AX-AC-AX-10`
I know the print function was actually performing `backspace` but is there way to assign the print value to a variable to get rid of backspace?
I already tried `str_var = str(i)` but it does not work

Here is a example

```
>>> test='                                                                                
--More-- \x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08         
\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08'
>>> print test

>>> repr(test)
"'                                                                                
--More-- \\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08         
\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x08'"
```

I don't understand why it shows like this and I want to assign the `print` output which is empty to a variable

Comment: You want to remove the backspaces?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I gather they don't want to print the backspaces.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Yes, I want to remove backspace but I want the backspace to perform the job

Comment: Why don't you just remove the backspaces? `str.replace('\b', '<backspace removed>')`

Comment: @zvone that will still leave `--More-- ` in the string

Comment: @georgewhr I understand what you need and I updated the title of your question. Also, you can see my answer.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon

Comment: It returns error `return re.sub(r'([^\x08]+)(\x08+)', lambda m: m[1][:-len(m[2])], s)
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: I think I understand the problem, `\x08` is called non-printing characters, which shouldn't be displayed

Comment: @georgewhr Please next time comment under the answer you are refering to, it is hard to keep track otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python itself does not treat a backspace specially. You can apply the backspaces by treating your string as a stack where a backspace pops the last character.

### Code

```
def do_backspace(s):
    chars = []
    for c in s:
        if c == '\b' and chars:
            chars.pop()
        else:
            chars.append(c)

    return ''.join(chars)

s = 'Original string: foo\b\b\b'
print(repr(s))

new_s = do_backspace(s)
print(repr(new_s))
```

Here, extra backspaces are ignored, but you could add a condition to treat them differently.

### Output

```
'Original string: foo\x08\x08\x08'
'Original string: '
```

Comment: You mean "backspace" rather than "backslash", right?

Comment: You have a bug - your backspace handling can only remove characters up to the previous backspace group, or the start of the string if there is no previous backspace group. For example, `'asdf\bg\b\b'` gets converted to `'asd'` instead of `'as'`. (Also, backspace handling is kind of iffy at the start of the string, but it's not clear what's supposed to happen there.)

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for pointing out. A regex based solution would need to run in a loop until no change is done. That is not guaranteed to be linear, so I switched to a stack based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Print `repr(some_line)`. This will show the escape (`\x08`) chars.